# Get QSqlField default value from mysql database

Tags: mysql, pyqt6

I'm using PyQt6 connecting to MySql database.
I created a QSqlRelationalTableModel then a QDataWidgetMapper to map a record to some widgets.
I insert a new record to the model, then position the datawidgetmapper to that record.
I don't get the default values from the database in the widgets.

I tried to print the `model.record().field(0).defaultValue()`, I always get None for all fields.

My question now, should the model get the default values from the database, or I have to set it using `QSqlField.setDefaultValue()`.

Edit1:
Now I tried to set the default values manually `model.record().field(i).setDefaultValue("someValue")` then `print(model.record().field(i).defaultValue()` I get `None`.

Tried it with a record form the database `db.record(tableName)` and get `None` too.

Edit2:
This case is a bug since Qt4. Thanks to thecodemonkey86 on github.

Edit3:
[QTBUG-122723](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-122723) raised

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to set/read QSqlRelationalTableModel column properties and constraints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130978/how-to-set-read-qsqlrelationaltablemodel-column-properties-and-constraints)

Comment: Use [`QSqlDatabase.record(tableName)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsqldatabase.html#record).

Comment: @musicamante I already came across this question and tried `QSqlDatabase.record(tableName)` and it gave me None for all the fields. I double checked mysql database and some fields have a default value (string fields, int fields and a date field)

Comment: @musicamante I also tried to `setDefaultValue()` and check the `defaultValue()` after that, it still gives me None. I tried the same with an access database, and got the same.
When I try `metaType()`, `isAutoValue()`, `requiredStatus()` I get the correct results.

Comment: The behavior might change depending on the database implementation (and the Qt database driver). I just tested it with sqlite and it works as expected.

Comment: @musicamante I tested it now with sqlite as you did, and yes it works. Though, when I inset a new record `record = model.record()` I don't get the default values and I had to assign them manually `record.setValue()`. BUT when I get the record from database (Sqlite) `QSqlDatabase.record(tableName)` I get the default values automatically.
Now, I need to find what is the case with MySql database or the driver.